# Cannot see Micro SD card in Gparted

Tags: gparted

Booting into System Rescue CD to make some space at the end of a Micro SD card with a Linux partition on it. I plug the Micro SD card into a Micro to SD card adaptor, then into the SD card slot in side of laptop.

Once booted `fdisk -l` shows it is visible to the kernel, but Gparted will only show me the inbuilt hard drive.

What is going on?

[image: Pic of Gparted and fdisk]

Answer (score 0):

You might try specifying the device path on the command line when invoking gparted.  For example:

```
sudo gparted /dev/mmcblk0
```

See [GParted Manual: Running gparted from a command line](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-run-from-cmd-line)

Also you might check if the latest GParted version is being used in the menu entry **Help -> About**.  The latest version is currently 1.4.0.

Comment: Will try. But the question remains, why is GParted not detecting what FDisk is, itself.

Comment: Without knowing more details one would only be guessing as to what the issue might be.  Did you check the list of devices in the menu: *GParted -> Devices*?

Comment: I did. Not in there. What details do you need bat what has already been asked of?

Comment: What version of GParted are you using?  Did you try the latest version as was suggested?

Comment: Version is in the screenshot above. Given the hassle I understand it is to update a package on a live version of Linux like SystemRescueCD, got new on the date of posting, especially permanently, would need to see changelog that MMCBLK devices are supported from a version later than is in this Linux distro to undergo that hassle.

Comment: This [GParted News item](https://gparted.org/news.php?item=240) indicates there was a fix for recognizing SD/MMC device names with the GParted 1.3.1 release.